# setting website path in iis 7

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, iis

I created some site on IIS and it's path is `http://localhost:13080/Broker.asmx`
But I want it to be under `http://localhost:13080/saCore/ws/Broker.asmx`.

How I can set this `/saCore/ws/` part under my site in IIS ?
or maybe it's possible to set this in my web.config.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Change your website's root (IIS Manager > Website > Basic Settings) to the folder that contains "saCore".

If "saCore" is not a real directory then you'll need to use the URI Rewriting module. It's a free download from Iis.net.